# How to update manually an R package in QGIS (folder rlibs)

Tags: qgis, r, qgis-plugins

[image]

I can't run an R script in QGIS because I need to update one package in the folder rlibs, which is where all the R packages are in QGIS.
Could someone tell me how to update manually a package in the folder rlibs.

Comment: If you can run a new R script in QGIS that just does one line: `install.packages("nameOfPackageToUpdate")` it should update that package in the default library location, which may or may not be this "rlibs" folder...

Comment: @Spacedman Many thanks. My aim is to update a package which has been divided into 8 packages. I have run a new script in QGIS as suggested by you, using install.packages("spatstat"), and all of them are updated except one, called spatstat.data; I have tried to run this package individually in a QGIS script, by using install.packages("spatstat.data"), but it doesn't work, and I don't know why. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Impossible to tell why `spatstat.data` won't install without seeing error messages and version numbers etc, and knowing your operating system. Sounds like a new problem, so open a new Q with all the details of this particular installation fail...

Comment: @Spacedman Thanks again. I will open a new Q. However, I have attached an image with the error message, just in case someone knows what the problem is. Apparently error is: lazy loading failed for package spatstat.data.

Comment: The message seems to be quite clear: spatstat.utils >= 3.0.0 is required.

Comment: @dimfalk if I install spatstat.utils 3.0.0 in R, can I copy its folder from C:/Users/david/Documents/R/win-library/4.0" and paste into the folder of R within QGIS, which is a different one. Both, R and R in QGIS use the same R version and are in the same computer. Would it work?

Comment: I'd also suggest to open a new question if you were not able to solve this with minimal effort.